# React native string.length return bad value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this function that reads a barcode, and then checks the code format,

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    KeyEvent.onKeyDownListener((keyEvent: KeyEventProps) => {
      if (keyEvent.keyCode === 61) {
        // tab char end of code
        const barcodeType = this.getBarcodeType(this.barcode);
        if (barcodeType) {
          this.props.barcodeSubject.next({barcode: this.barcode});
        }
        this.setState({barcode: this.barcode, barcodeType});
        this.barcode = '';
        return;
      }
      this.barcode += keyEvent.pressedKey;
    });
  }

 getBarcodeType(input: string): Format | undefined {
    const ean13Pattern = /^[0-9]{13}$/gm;
    const ean8Pattern = /^[0-9]{8}$/;
    const ean128Pattern = /^[(0-9A-Za-z)]+$/;
    console.log(
      '***',
      input,
      typeof input,
      input.length,
      input.match(ean13Pattern),
    );
    if (ean13Pattern.test(input)) {
      return 'EAN';
    } else if (ean8Pattern.test(input)) {
      return 'EAN';
    } else if (ean128Pattern.test(input)) {
      return 'CODE128';
    }
    return undefined;
  }
```

The problem is that the regex never matches, and when I do,

```js
console.log(
   '***',
   input,
   typeof input,
   input.length,
   input.match(ean13Pattern),
);
```

**Output:**

`LOG  *** 5449000214911 string 26 null`

I got 26 as length instead of 13, can someone tell me why?

Comment: You are logging `input.trim().length,` and probably you have white spaces or new lines in the input. Try logging `input.length` itself. Also, the `gm` at the end of Regex does not mean it will match multi lines which in total have 13 chars. But it will match multi lines where each line has 13 chars

Comment: `console.log(escape(input));`

Comment: with or without trim / escape changes nothing

Comment: Look at each byte in the string and see what they actually are. That it's double the length you think implies there's additional data.

Answer (score 0):

I used spread on string and then i saw that my string contains many non-printable chars

```
console.log([...input].join(','));
```

to replace invisible chars i used

```
input.replace(/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\x9F]/g, '')
```

i don't know if it's a good solution but it workes for me.